# Code onset from event occurrence

Tags: r

I have a vector that gives presence/absence of an event (insurgency in this case) over time, and I'd like to create another vector that gives onset of the event, i.e.:

```
occurrence <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
onset <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

The following loop will get what I need:

```
answer <- 0
for (t in 2:length(occurrence) {
  answer[t] <- ifelse((occurrence[t]-occurrence[t-1])==1, 1, 0)
}

> answer
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pmax()` and `diff()`:

```
c(NA, pmax(0, diff(occurrence)))
 [1] NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0
```

This works because `diff()` calculates the difference between successive elements, resulting in `1` for every start.  Then you need to remove the `0` and `-1` values. `pmax` is a *parallel* version of `max()` and is handy to change all `-1s` to zero

```
diff(occurrence)
[1]  0 -1  0  1 -1  0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the prior time interval to the current one and chose those where 0 is followed by one with this code:

```
> c(0, as.numeric(occurrence[-length(occurrence)] == 0 & occurrence[-1]==1) )
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

(I padded it with a leading 0 because you didn't want leading occurrence:1's to be counted as new events.)